# how can I achieve header files mutual exclusive include?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have two headers: `a.h` and `b.h`.
What I want to do in my project is to allow only one of them included.
If both `a.h` and `b.h` are included in a source file, a compile error is expected to occur.
What shall I add in the headers to achieve this?

```
#include<a.h> // Ok
```

---

```
#include<b.h> // OK
```

---

```
#include<a.h>
#include<b.h> // compile error
```

Comment: @Prodigle You probably misunderstood the OP's question.

Comment: What if they are used exclusively but each in different translation units? Is that fine or do you want to prohibit that as well?

Comment: @molbdnilo Good point. That would be a hard(er) nut to crack. Do you have an idea how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If both `a.h` and `b.h` are included in a source file, a compile error is expected to occur.
>   What shall I add in the headers to achieve this?

You can do something like this with the preprocessor referring to your header guards:

`a.h`

```
 #ifndef A_H
 #define A_H
 #ifdef B_H
 #error "You cannot use a.h in combination with b.h"
 #endif

 // ...

 #endif
```

---

`b.h`

```
 #ifndef B_H
 #define B_H
 #ifdef A_H
 #error "You cannot use b.h in combination with a.h"
 #endif

 // ...

 #endif
```